# How to display only once same push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm using push notifications on my app, and i didn't find a way to display only once notifications that have same content.
Is that possible ?

My code :

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate, GCMReceiverDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var gcmSenderID: String?
    var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: [category]))
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

        let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
        gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
        GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                               kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                                                                 scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({(error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to GCM")
            }
        })
    }

    func onTokenRefresh() {
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }

    func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if(registrationToken != nil) {
            print(registrationToken)
        }else{
            print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Google Cloud Messaging for push notification into my app

Thank's in advance

Comment: what do you mean? Are you sending the same push message multiple times? Why?

Comment: my app can share data between multiple user, so when someone update data the others user get notifications, i want the notification to be displayed only once, i don't want user to have multiple notifications for the same type, i'm using gcm if it can help

Comment: Can you add the code you're currently using for handing your push notifications in the original post so we can help you better?

Comment: I updated my original post